# Azure Queue Listener - On-premise Azure Queue Listener

Tags: azure, .net-core, cloud, azure-queues

I have a scenario that our Azure environment can't connect to on-premise, but on-premise can connect to Azure. So a service call from Azure to on-premise to be done using a middleware wrapper. I am thinking to use an azure queue. From On-premise, a listener looking for azure queue entries. If any message noticed in azure queue, listener call on-premise API and put the response to azure queue. Another listener in azure will fetch this data. But now I am doubting about on-premise azure queue listener. Because I noticed that azure queue listeners are deployed and running inside Azure environment itself. I couldn't see a Ref. for azure queue listeners running from -on-premise environment, listening to Azure.  Any one tried this or any lead on this approach?

Comment: `But now I am doubting about on-premise azure queue listener` - Please edit your question and elaborate more on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating an Azure File share and then local drive map it inside on-premise. So now whatever dropped in Azure File are accessible in both Azure and on-premise. I also written a FileSystemWatcher in on-premise so that any dropped information can be processed immediately. I am not sure about sync-up lag across Azure and On-Premise for Azure File share. I keep this thread open for more days for any additional comments or suggestions.